# How to know which module to import?

Tags: plutus, haskell, on-chain

Let's say my smartcontract needs **BuiltinData**.
Quicksearch in documentation reveals that **BuiltinData** is in:

- Plutus.V1.Ledger.Api
- Plutus.V2.Ledger.Api
- PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal
- PlutusTx
- PlutusTx.Builtins
- PlutusTx.Prelude
- ...

How to know which include I should add? Which ones are preferred and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these are reexported versions of others. This means some of them are not necessary. Also `PlutusTx.Prelude` should be included in all projects as it maps types into `PlutusTx` which complies with the bytecode that runs on the chain.

This means if your Data type is in `PlutusTx.Prelude`, you should not need the other modules in general. The exception is if other parts of your code use that module.